# Which style to convert hex string to integer

Tags: sql-server

I have a field in the SQL Server, belong to an antique application which **I am not sure which kind of data this field represent**.

I know this field to be primary key and would like to order by it, using conversion to integer. I found the conversion [support multiple styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#binary-styles).

```
SELECT TOP(5000) oid,
convert(int, convert(varbinary, oid,2)) as Style2,
convert(int, convert(varbinary, oid,0)) as Style0
```

Result into

```
C9AEEC304776000200FD000000710005    7405573     925970480
C9AEEC304776000200FD000000980007    9961479     959983664
C9AEEC304776000200FD000000980008    9961480     959983664
C9AEEC304776000200FD000000980009    9961481     959983664
C9AEEC304776000200FD00000098000A    9961482     959983664
C9AEEC304776000200FD000001180001    18350081    825765936
C9AEEC304776000200FD000001180002    18350082    825765936
C9AEEC304776000200FD000001180003    18350083    825765936
```

Seems like the style 0 skip some final characters. Is the style number 2 correct or I have been wrong, trying to use this kind of conversion the from the start?

Comment: You have a 128-bit binary value. Neither int nor bigint can represent it. You may get away with two bigints.

Comment: Thanks @GSerg , So if I keep the varbinary form and skip the conversion to integer, shall the ordering still be correct? also which style is the correct one to apply on this 128-bit binary value

Comment: What happens when you simply order by it?

Comment: Ordering as varchar is not good. But ordering as varbinary seems to be OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As GSerg has pointed out in the comments, this value is too large to convert to a SQL Server `int` or `bigint` type - if you do so, you will be losing bytes. You can see this if you run:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(0xC9AEEC304776000200FD000000710005 AS INT) AS VARBINARY(16))
```

which will return `0x00710005` - the last four bytes of the input value

---

To answer your question about binary conversion styles (even though you probably don't need it now):

- Style 0 is equivalent to `SELECT CAST(CAST('C9AEEC304776000200FD000000710005' AS VARBINARY) AS INT)` - i.e. the value is cast to binary as a string.
- Style 2 treats the string as hexadecimal - functionally equivalent to `SELECT CAST(0xC9AEEC304776000200FD000000710005 AS INT)`
- (Although you didn't ask, style 1 works the same as style 2 but requires that the hexadecimal string value includes the leading `0x` characters)